# HorizontalScrollBar inverted direction

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have a horizontal scroll bar on my table view, but the direction is inverted.Normaly, the scroll start at left, and when i press and push to right the internal component go ahead to right too. I my case, the scroll bar start at right and the component start left, and when i press and push to left, my component go to right. How to fix that?

More over, i dont have external ResourceDictionary
This is my header about gridcontrol/table view

```
    <dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridControl"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                     Margin="8,0,8,0"
                     Padding="0"
                     PreviewKeyDown="gridControl_PreviewKeyDown"
                     SelectedItems="{Binding Selection}"
                     SelectionMode="Row"
                     ShowLoadingPanel="False">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView Name="tableView1"
                           AllowBestFit="True"
                           AllowConditionalFormattingMenu="False"
                           AllowEditing="False"
                           AlternateRowBackground="#FFEFF0EF"
                           AutoWidth="False"
                           RowDoubleClick="tableView1_RowDoubleClick"
                           SearchPanelHighlightResults="False"
                           ShowGroupPanel="False"
                           ShowSearchPanelCloseButton="False"
                           ShowSearchPanelMode="Never" HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Auto">
```

I tried add external scroll bar, but i was unsuccessful